# Disable bootstrap 5 Responsive font sizes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

What is the easiest way to disable [RFS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/typography/#responsive-font-sizes) in bootstrap 5?

I tried:

```
$font-size-base: 1.6rem;
$font-size-lg: $font-size-base;
$font-size-sm: $font-size-base;
```

But `reboot.scss` seems to override it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

override `$enable-rfs` to false.

`$enable-rfs: false;`

Comment: This is nice and simple, but it would be much more helpful for others to include information such as where you make this change and so forth.  It's not a complete answer, in my opinion because it lacks sufficient details.

Comment: more info about all Bootstrap options: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/options/